# Transforming CSV into SQL with Notepad++

Tags: notepad++, regex, csv

Suppose I have a CSV file like this:

```
1,"abc",,,,
2,"def",,,"ghi",
3,,"jkl",,,"mno"
```

Now I need to transform it in 3 steps:

1. Replace all empty spaces with the String `NULL`
2. Add at the beginning of **each line** the String `VALUES (`
3. Add at the end of **each line** the string `);`

So that I have:

```
VALUES (1,"abc",NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL);
VALUES (2,"def",NULL,NULL,"ghi",NULL);
VALUES (3,NULL,"jkl",NULL,NULL,"mno");
```

I would like to use Notepad++ or something similar.

This is needed in order to transform the csv into a valid sql file.

Comment: You can do it by using "Replace" of Notepad++ with RegEx (regular expression)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe I got it down to two find/replace expressions.

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> to bring up the Replace dialog.

```
1,"abc",,,,
2,"def",,,"ghi",
3,,"jkl",,,"mno"
```

Find what:    `^([^,]*),([^,]*),([^,]*),([^,]*),([^,]*),([^,]*)$` 
Replace with: `VALUES\(NULL\1,NULL\2,NULL\3,NULL\4,NULL\5,NULL\6\);`

```
VALUES(NULL1,NULL"abc",NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL);
VALUES(NULL2,NULL"def",NULL,NULL,NULL"ghi",NULL);
VALUES(NULL3,NULL,NULL"jkl",NULL,NULL,NULL"mno");
```

Find what: `NULL([^,\)])` 
Replace with: `\1`

```
VALUES(1,"abc",NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL);
VALUES(2,"def",NULL,NULL,"ghi",NULL);
VALUES(3,NULL,"jkl",NULL,NULL,"mno");
```

Comment: Looks good, +1 !

Comment: Looks OK, since it offers no explanation of what is going on, which may actually help the OP learn something. +0

Comment: Basically adds `Null` after every comma. Then removes null wherever there is some value after it.